# Codeceptjs with Nightmare doesn't output result of test

Tags: javascript, acceptance-testing, nightmare, codeceptjs

Basically, I did everything as described in `get started` section on http://codecept.io/ page.

devDependencies from package.json:

```
"codeceptjs": "^0.5.1",
"nightmare": "^2.10.0",
"nightmare-upload": "^0.1.1"
```

codecept.json:

```
{
  "tests": "./tests/acceptance/*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "helpers": {
    "Nightmare": {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "show": false,
      "restart": false
    }
  },
  "include": {},
  "bootstrap": false,
  "mocha": {},
  "name": "vagrant"
}
```

The test itself is also from tutorial:

```
Feature('My first test');

Scenario('test something', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('http://yahoo.com');
    I.fillField('p', 'github nightmare');
    I.click('Search Web');
    I.waitForElement('#main');
    I.seeElement('#main .searchCenterMiddle li a');
    I.seeElement("//a[contains(@href,'github.com/segmentio/nightmare')]");
    I.see('segmentio/nightmare','#main li a');
});
```

When I run `codeceptjs run --steps` I get an output in console:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP2dE.png)

It doesn't matter is test should pass or fail, output is always the same.

Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I managed it to work. The problem was virtual buffer (I run codeceptjs from inside vagrant).
The solution is simple and common in such cases but I totally forget about it.

You need to run codeceptjs with `xvfb`. It looks like this:

```
xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1024x768x24' codeceptjs run --steps
```

Don't forget to install all necessary libraries before:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libjpeg-dev libgif-dev g++ git-all xvfb libgtk2.0-0 dbus-x11 -y;
sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev -y;
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable -y;
```